Are there $x,y\in G$ such that $\langle x\rangle \cap C_G(y)=1$?
I am working on a conjecture involving certain types of binary algebraic structures. At the current stage of the project, my team and I have arrived at a purely group-theoretic reformulation of a specific case, which is implied by the more general problem stated below. Any new ideas or attempts would be greatly appreciated. Here is the problem: Prove or disprove the following statement:
$(\ast)$ Let $G$ be a finite group generated by a conjugacy class $\mathcal{C}$ such that $Z(G)=1$. Then there are $x,y\in\mathcal{C}$ such that $\langle x\rangle \cap C_G(y)=1$.
Examples

$S_n$ is centerless and generated by the class of transpositions. $(\ast)$ is true for $S_n$ with $x=(1 2)$ and $y=(1 3)$.
$A_n$ is centerless and generated by the class of $3-$cycles. $(\ast)$ is true for $A_n$ with $x=(1 2 3)$ and $y=(1 3 4)$.
For $n$ odd, the dihedral group $D_n=\langle r,s\ \colon r^n=s^2=1,srs^{-1}=r^{-1}\rangle$ is centerless and generated by the conjugacy class $\{r,sr,sr^2,\dots, sr^{n-1}\}$. $(\ast)$ is true for $D_n$, with odd $n$, with $x=sr$ and $y=r$.

Approaches & Remarks

The claim is true for all groups $G$ with $|G|\le 1000$ (excluding orders $512$ and $768$, for which GAP is on holiday).
We can assume that $G/G^\prime$ is cyclic (this is an equivalent
condition of $G$ being generated by a single conjugacy class,
according to Lemma 3.1 of this paper).
The condition in the claim is symmetric on $x$ and $y$, that is, for conjugate elements $x,y\in G$ the properties $\langle x\rangle \cap C_G(y)=1$ and $\langle y\rangle \cap C_G(x)=1$ are equivalent. Indeed if $y=gxg^{-1}$ for some $g\in G$ and $\langle x\rangle \cap C_G(y)=1$, then $1=\langle x\rangle\cap gC_G(x)g^{-1}$, and this holds if and only if $1=g^{-1}g=g^{-1}\langle x\rangle g\cap C_G(x)=\langle y\rangle\cap C_G(x)$.

Important
Although it may appear straightforward, this is not a textbook exercise, so I cannot provide any sources for it. I will keep this question updated in the Examples and Approaches sections if and when I happen to reach any progress in the resolution.

What is your question?

@DerekHolt: "Prove or disprove the following statement:" and then the statement, (*).

Perhaps I am being hypercritical, but posters are supposed to ask questions, not just state problems, so it should say something like "I am stuck on the following problem, can someone help me solve it?". It would also be helpful to know the source of the probIem, such as an exercise number in a textbook.  I don't know the answer and I hope the question is improved and gets re-opened. Note that in a counterexample the order of $x\in C$ would be divisible by at least two primes.

(1) This problem is not a textbook exercise but arose during the investigation of my current research project. Since it is purely group theoretical and easy to understand, I thought some experts here could provide valuable insight, and I chose this simple formulation as a question, as I have seen in other posts. I have read the general directions on how to formulate a question on MSE multiple times, and I have invested a lot of time and effort in providing examples and describing the approaches I have tried.

(2) I am, of course, willing to edit and adjust details if you suggest a better reformulation. I trust your experience and expertise; however, I still do not understand why you chose to close the question directly before asking for a source in the comments and waiting for my answer.

$\newcommand{\ang}[1]{\langle #1\rangle}$One quick (perhaps trivial) observation: in all your examples, $\mathcal C$ consists of elements of prime order, and in this case the claim is straightforward: if $\ang{x}\cap C_G(y)\neq 1$ for all $y\in\mathcal C$, then $\ang{x}\cap C_G(y)=\ang{x}$, so in $x$ is central, contradicting $Z(G)=1$. A similar argument works whenever $\ang{x}$ has a unique minimal (nontrivial) subgroup, i.e., whenever $|x|$ is a prime power. Perhaps it would be useful to look for an example where the elements of $\mathcal C$ have order divisible by two primes?
